# Как сохранить модель машинного обучения в файл?

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение

Возможно ли сохранить обученную модель машинного обучения в файл и открыть этот файл в другом .py файле?

Пробовал joblib и pickle. Эти способы сработали только в рамках одного файла (обучаю модель, сохраняю в файл, загружаю в нем же). Но при обучении и сохранении в одном .py файле и загрузке модели для предсказания в другом .py файле возникает ошибка.

в первом файле:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
clf.fit(df_train,df_train_target)
joblib.dump(clf, "model.pkl")
```

во втором:

```
clf2 = joblib.load("model.pkl")
y_pred = clf2.predict(df_val)
```

ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке на скрине, проблема не в загрузке модели - она загрузилась нормально, а в том, что вы подаете ей на вход необработанные строки вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделайте такой же препроцесинг данных, которые вы подаете модели на вход, какой вы делали для обучающей выборки. Ну или хотя бы убедитесь, что в обучающей выборке и в данных, которые вы скармливаете модели, одинаковые типы данных и размерности матриц.

Comment: Точно... Совсем забыл про это